# Wordpress - deregister_script jquery wont work

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am using Wordpress 3.5.2 right now and I am working on my own theme. When I look at the complete sourcecode - wordpress always imports its own jquery script.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://my.domain.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3'></script>
```

But I want to include my own jquery file on top - so I saw this function:

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
```

But this solution wont work for me - the Code above is still in my Sourcecode.

Whats wrong here and how can I deregister the wordpress-jquery import?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_script):

> De-registers the WordPress stock jquery script, so you can register your own copy or from the Google CDN

It doesn't add a new jquery script.  You could either link a script with a handle previously registered using the `wp_register_script()` you'll need to do it manually, like so:

```
wp_register_script('jquery', 'path/to/your/own/jquery/file', false, 'jquery_version');

wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

Documentation: **[`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script), [`wp_register_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script)**

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('jquery', 'path_to_your_jquery-file', false, 'jquery_version');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

It should work.